# could not load or find assembly Microsoft.Azure.cosmos.table

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

I have a windows forms application `WinFormsProj`, which references a class library project named `ModelsProj`.
`ModelsProj` has dependency to `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table` version 1.0.7.0.
At runtime, when `WinFormsProj` reaches this code, raises a `FileNotFoundException` saying that `could not load or find assemble` Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table`:

```
var entityTypes = typeof(EntityBase).Assembly.GetExportedTypes()
            .Where(t => t.GetInterface(typeof(IDto).FullName) == null
                        && t.GetInterface(typeof(IEntity).FullName) != null && !t.IsAbstract);
```

`EntityBase` is the base type of all of my model entities, and is located in `ModelProj`.

I can solve the exception by just adding a reference to `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table` in `WinFormsProj`.
However, I expect the program work without doing this!
My question is : Why isn't the dll of `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table` getting copied to the output? Isn't the build process supposed to put all the needed dlls in output directory?

I've found [here](https://medium.com/@RupaniChirag/how-to-resolve-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies-and-why-this-cf8d48d788eb) that a common cause is that a project and one if its dependencies, depend on different versions of the same package. That is not my case, `WinFormsProj` does not need to reference any version of `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table` itself!

---

**further info:**
I've used `fuslogvw.exe` to inspect what happens and here is its log:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (8/12/2020 @ 10:25:22 AM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  H:\melkradar-git\melkradar\src\MelkRadar\Mgmt\MelkRadar.Mgmt.Win\bin\Debug\MelkRadar.Mgmt.Win.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table, Version=1.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///H:/melkradar-git/melkradar/src/MelkRadar/Mgmt/MelkRadar.Mgmt.Win/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = MelkRadar.Mgmt.Win.exe
Calling assembly : MelkRadar.Core.Model, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: H:\melkradar-git\melkradar\src\MelkRadar\Mgmt\MelkRadar.Mgmt.Win\bin\Debug\MelkRadar.Mgmt.Win.exe.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table, Version=1.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///H:/melkradar-git/melkradar/src/MelkRadar/Mgmt/MelkRadar.Mgmt.Win/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///H:/melkradar-git/melkradar/src/MelkRadar/Mgmt/MelkRadar.Mgmt.Win/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///H:/melkradar-git/melkradar/src/MelkRadar/Mgmt/MelkRadar.Mgmt.Win/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file://
```

BTW, I've tried cleaning the solution, restarting VS, rebuilding and trying again, suggested in similar questions. it didn't work.